# Bootstrap grid system row content overlapping other row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a problem with grid system of bootstrap, I've 6 elements inside a row, each one with class set to "col-md-2", the problem is that the only first 5 elements are shown on the row, and the 6º jumps to 2nd row. So the 2nd row gets empty spaces.

See the picture.

[image]

a piece of code:

```
<div id="card-listing" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 cardthumnb" data-time="1396739650" data-name="Graceful Charity">
              <a id="card-55" href="http://127.0.0.1/~victor/yugiohguia/cards/graceful-charity/">
                <div class="card-thunmb">
                  <img src="http://127.0.0.1/~victor/yugiohguia/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/GracefulCharity-LCYW-EN-ScR-1E.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="card-title">
                  <span>Graceful Charity</span>
                </div>
             </a>
        </div>
        <!-- other 5 images... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

the only css applied is:

```
.cardthumnb img {
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}

.cardthumnb .card-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[see live](http://yugiohguia.6te.net/cartas/)

Comment: In your question, you said each class is set as `col-md-6` but it is set as `col-md-2` in your code. Which one do you use actually?  The correct one should be `col-md-2`.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, yeah it's col-md-2 actually in code.

Comment: It should work. Can you put your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @LVarayut added live link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about bootstrap, but your isotope settings.
Make sure you have your configuration object setup correctly, or make a question targeting isotope.